# How to create a series of variables automatically?

Tags: python-2.7

How can I create a series of variables automatically with python?
Like this:

```html
tmp1=1;
tmp2=1;
tmp3=1;
tmp4=1;
tmp5=1；
```

Comment: I don't think you can produce variable names with code...never heard of any language that can do that. Instead, if you need to store various values, a list or something similar might be better.

Comment: Wouldn't a list or array be more suitable? Please describe some more of why you need this series of variables and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am using a django model to create a table that don't need exactly attributes, so I decide use a series of attributes that mean nothing.like this：
` from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Title(models.Model):
        text1=models.TextField()
        text2=models.TextField()
        text3=models.TextField()
        text4=models.TextField()
        text5=models.TextField()
        ...
        text100=models.TextField()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you dynamically create variables in Python via a while loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop). you have several ways to do that:

- Use dict or collection instead
- Using globals
- Using the exec() method

About the first solution (dict or collection) - is not actually what you asked for, which is to create a variable in the global scope.. but I would go with that anytime. I don't see really any reason why I'd need to create variables dynamically instead of using some datatype.
I would say that using both globals and exec() method for this is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Store them in a dictionary

```
d = {}
value = ['a','b','c']

for key in range(1, 3):
    d[key]= value[key]
print d
> {0:'a',1:'b',2:'c'}
print d[0]
> 'a'
```

(Comments? I am new to python too!)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got an answer somewhere:

```html
for i in range(100):
    locals()['tmp%d'%i]=1
```

or:

```html
>>> for i in range(1, 10):
...     exec 'tmp' + str(i) + '=1'
```

I don't know if I have a ambiguity describe, the above two is exactly I want.